# CoreData not firing faults

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am working on a *Tabbed Application* and have been struggling with a `CoreData` issue for a while now. I will do my best to be clear enough.

The app starts with a tab, which fetches certain types of objects from `CoreData` (together with their To-Many relationship) and displays the data in a certain way. In another tab, I have a `UITableView`, which uses `NSFetchedResultsController` to display different kind of objects. Both tabs use the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. There are additional tabs that do not use CoreData or any previously retrieved objects.

When I enter the first tab, everything works and is displayed correctly. When I navigate from there to a tab which doesn't use CoreData and go back again, everything is still fine. However, when I navigate to the tab with the `UITableView` and `NSFetchedResultsController` then back again, my objects in the first tab are faulted. This doesn't surprise me much, but I can't seem to be able to fire them. I am trying to access object's To-Many relationship and the `count` value, which - from what I know - should fire a faulted object.

I am not sure what to think about this behaviour. Can it be that the `NSFetchedResultsController` somehow messes up previous fetches? That doesn't sound reasonable...

Also, just so you know, I am using Swift, but that should not be affecting anything.

Any input will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You say *"my objects in the first tab are faulted"*, but what are you actually seeing? Does it say `<fault>` in the UI?

Comment: yes, it did say <fault>. i don't know how exactly, but after some refactoring I got things to work..

Comment: Will you please provide more detail on what exactly you refactored to get things working. I am facing the same issue and seeking help to resolve. One thing to notice is this just take place in swift.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this kind of question without seeing the actual code. However it appears your `fetchResultController`'s results are being changed during the navigation. A good practice would be, try to execute your `fetchRequest` and feed it to the `fetchResultController` in your ViewController's `viewWillAppear`.